# I have a string with pipe and double forward slash separated, that I need to format in an excel file as output in java

Tags: java, xml, excel, dom, text-files

I am getting the data as a string in java while reading the similar tags from XML file. and that data is pipe(|) separated and double forward slash(//) separated for each of them.
Sharing you three strings in a tag available which need to convert in excel format as tab separated.

```
Information - Desktop | Telecom//Apple Mac//iPhone//Working with iPhone
Infrastructure - Desktop | Telecommunication//Apple iPod//iPad
Information - Desktop | Telecom//Apple Mac//iTunes 10//Settings//Troubleshooting
```

- These are the 3 strings which I am fetching through XML using DOM parser in java.
- The string I need want to convert for excel as tab separated txt file.
- The format of the output file would be,

[image: OUTPUT FORMAT]

Please suggest me how can I achieve the loop to get the out like this one.

Comment: Interesting problem.Question: In cell C4, how did you get `Knowledge Category: DH Apple Mac`? Shouldn't it be `Knowledge Category: Apple Mac`? And in Cell C5, how did you get `Knowledge Category: DH iTunes 10`? Shouldn't it be `Knowledge Category: iPhone` ?

Comment: Yes in cell C4 it be Knowledge Category: Apple Mac and in cell C5 it will be Knowledge Category:iPhone. It is done by mistake, as I am also doing some experiment with the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this. I am able to output the data in a CSV format, perhaps you want to use an API to write it to an Excel file.

```
public class StringToExcelProblem {

    static String INPUT_DATA = 
              "Information - Desktop | Telecom//Apple Mac//iPhone//Working with iPhone\n"
            + "Infrastructure - Desktop | Telecommunication//Apple iPod//iPad\n"
            + "Information - Desktop | Telecom//Apple Mac//iTunes 10//Settings//Troubleshooting\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(INPUT_DATA, "\n");
        List<Block> allBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String blockData = st.nextToken();
            String[] st2 = blockData.split(" \\| ");
            String parent = st2[0];
            String labels = st2[1];
            StringTokenizer st3 = new StringTokenizer(labels, "//");
            int index = 0;
            Block block = null;
            while(st3.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String label = st3.nextToken();
                if(index == 0){
                    block = new Block(parent, label);
                    index ++;
                } else {
                    block.add(label);
                }
                parent = label;
            }
            allBlocks.add(block);
        }
        for(Block b: allBlocks) {
            for(RowObj r: b.rows){
                System.out.println(r);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class RowObj {
    String label;
    String value;
    String parentId;
    String active;
    String parentTable;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label + "," + value + "," + parentId + "," + active + "," + parentTable;
    }
}

class Block {
    List<RowObj> rows;

    public Block(String parent, String name) {
        RowObj row = new RowObj();
        row.label = name;
        row.value = name.toLowerCase();
        row.parentId = "Knowledge Base: " + parent;
        row.active = "TRUE";
        row.parentTable = "k_knowledge_base";

        rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add(row);
    }

    public void add(String name) {
        RowObj parent = rows.get(rows.size()-1);

        RowObj row = new RowObj();
        row.label = name;
        row.value = name.toLowerCase();
        row.parentId = "Knowledge Category: " + parent.label;
        row.active = "TRUE";
        row.parentTable = "k_category";

        rows.add(row);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rows.toString();
    }
}
```

I am able to generate the following output. It is the same as what you have in your screenshot. Only difference is, this is in a CSV format. You only have to format it as you need.

```
Telecom,telecom,Knowledge Base: Information - Desktop,TRUE,k_knowledge_base
Apple Mac,apple mac,Knowledge Category: Telecom,TRUE,k_category
iPhone,iphone,Knowledge Category: Apple Mac,TRUE,k_category
Working with iPhone,working with iphone,Knowledge Category: iPhone,TRUE,k_category

Telecommunication,telecommunication,Knowledge Base: Infrastructure - Desktop,TRUE,k_knowledge_base
Apple iPod,apple ipod,Knowledge Category: Telecommunication,TRUE,k_category
iPad,ipad,Knowledge Category: Apple iPod,TRUE,k_category

Telecom,telecom,Knowledge Base: Information - Desktop,TRUE,k_knowledge_base
Apple Mac,apple mac,Knowledge Category: Telecom,TRUE,k_category
iTunes 10,itunes 10,Knowledge Category: Apple Mac,TRUE,k_category
Settings,settings,Knowledge Category: iTunes 10,TRUE,k_category
Troubleshooting,troubleshooting,Knowledge Category: Settings,TRUE,k_category
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have added header and the logic works fine to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take these three iterative steps in order to import your multi-delimited, non-standard xml data into MS Excel.

---

**STEP 1: IMPORT DATA**

Open `Excel` → Select Cell `B2` → `Data` Ribbon → `From Text` icon (`Get External Data` group) → Choose `.\yourFile.xml` → Select `delimited` from the "Text Import Wizard" window → Hit `next` → Select only `other` → Type `|`(for your delimiter) → Hit `finish` → Hit `ok`

---

**STEP 2: EXPORT REMAINDER**

Highlight all of the contents in `column C` → `Copy` selection → Open `Notepad` (notepad.exe) → `Paste` contents → `Save` notepad file `.\yourFile2.xml`

---

**STEP 3: IMPORT REMAINDER**

`Activate` Excel → Select `Column C` → `Delete` Column C → Select `cell C2` → `Data` Ribbon → `From Text` icon (`Get External Data` group) → Choose `.\yourFile.xml` → Select `delimited` from the "Text Import Wizard" window → Hit `next` → Select only `other` → Type `/` (for your delimiter) → Select 'treat consecutive delimiters as one' → Hit `finish` → Hit `ok`.

---

After performing these three steps you should have your XML data separated in the manner you depicted above (with the use of this is built-in MS Excel functionality).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have those string values in java body, and I am parsing that XML in java to get 4 output file, I have done with 3 output files but for 4th one I am confused how to implement that string value  to get the output in the desired format( txt file- which I import in excel as tab separated).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Nevertheless, have you tried to copy the data portion of the parsed file into a separate text editor (like notepad)? You can save that data as a `.txt`. Excel handles .txt files very well. Let me know.

Comment: XML data contains so many tags in is for multiple HTML pages, from which one tag contain those values, which I am arsing into TXT file only, as tab separated, which will be handled as tab delimiter in excel file. So I need to know the Java logic to partition all the string value to convert it into text file.